# Remote desktop control component (like vnc)

Tags: delphi, remote-access, vnc

I want to embed a remote control feature to support users of my application.

Currently, I'm using the VNC but I would like to find another solution like a component or VNC delphi implementation.

**Now looking for a free or opensource solution.**

Comment: When you search the web for `delphi vnc` the first hit is: http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphivnc/ Did you look at that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided use Ultra VNC Repeater.

http://www.uvnc.com/products/uvnc-repeater.html

With it I can use only one port for all remote controls, and force the server (customer side) to request remote control (vncviewer).

Also, the customer doesn't needs to open ports for input at his firewall.

Works great and it's free.

Answer (score 4):

[Nexus Portal](http://www.nexusdb.com/support/index.php?q=portal) is a good Delphi library for implementing remote support in your applications.

It is based on the [RTC SDK library](http://www.realthinclient.com/) for HTTP/HTTPS communication.

Comment: There is no free for commercial use solution?

Comment: @Beto Nothing in your questions mentions a requirement for free software. Please edit the question to include all the details. I hate it when the key requirements leak out in comments to answers. If you want free, try VNC.

Answer (score 3):

Some time ago, I made an UltraVnc dll (both server and client) and a Delphi wrapper for both dlls. I modified the original Ultra VNC sources to start/stop the server, add a new viewer, etc.

Original post:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/110131086673878874356/posts/gAmBogWarww
https://plus.google.com/u/0/110131086673878874356/posts/dbMRPcUkKAe

Direct link to source + binaries:
https://github.com/andremussche/UltraVncAsDll

Comment: Links are dead.

Comment: new link is https://github.com/andremussche/UltraVncAsDll @amaninlove

Answer (score 2):

AllaKore_Remote open source

https://github.com/Maickonn/AllaKore_Remote

- Connection ID and Password.
- Remote access with RFB algorithm (Send only what has changed on the screen).
- Data Compression (zLib).
- Sharer files.
- Chat.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Remote Assistant from Context Software:

http://www.contextsoft.com/products/remassist/